# Custom docker image logs are incomplete

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have a task where I need to built a Docker Compose stack for a Wordpress with HTTPS support. So there I have a custom built images based on Ubuntu 20.04 and patterned on official image equivalents for these images. In short everythings works on these custom images besides the log part. I do have 2 projects - one for official images and one for custom built images.

The actual logs on the container `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log` looks like it:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.80.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Wed Feb 15 16:36:15.477371 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 15 16:36:15.477397 2023] [core:notice] [pid 8] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Where the `docker logs` does give logs looking like that:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.80.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

I have the same issue for 3 custom built containers.

Their CMD or ENTRYPOINT 's look like this:

```
CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "nginx -g 'daemon off;' & exec tail -f /var/log/nginx/*.log"]
```

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "/usr/sbin/mysqld --init-file=/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql --log-error-verbosity=3 --general_log=1 --general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/general.log --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log & exec tail -f /var/log/mysql/*.log"]
```

I need to use tail for 2/3 of these containers because without it there are no logs whatsoever.

In the case of `apache2ctl` there is no need to use `tail` but the result is the same for all of these containers - logs are being displayed only once and they appear to be incomplete, they do not seem to update in real time like they would do for official images.

I have built a custom ubuntu based image with Python3 and simple printing out script and in that case it prints forever (logs get updated) - same behavior like for a regular shell.

I spent a lot of time testing different possibilities and I'm going nowhere with it, so I am here to ask why it's the case for these custom built images and how can I make it so the logging is continuous and complete like it is the case for the official images.

Comment: I would try getting rid of those `tail` commands.  Take a look at how docker's nginx official  does it (https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile-debian.template)  - with symlinks - and I think for mysql you can just log to `/dev/stderr`

Comment: @erik258 Yes I want to get rid of those `tail` commands but at least now I can't. I have tried ```ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log``` that is available in the Dockerfile you have linked but with no success. There appear empty log contents with `docker logs` if I get rid of the `tail` and link it the same way it's done in the official Dockerfile.